# Cmakejs Electron build error. Can't find header files for node v18.16.1

Tags: node.js, electron, cmake-js

I'm trying to bind a massive cpp project that building with Cmake to my client app in Electron context. I altered CmakeList.txt to build *.node extensions and managed to run in in js side but when i try to use it with electron it gives error like mismatching NODE_MODULE_VERSION's. I tried electron mode of Cmakejs but then it couldn't find needed header file from Electron.
There is for node v18.0.0 https://artifacts.electronjs.org/headers/dist/v18.0.0/x64/node.lib
but there is not for node v18.16.1 https://artifacts.electronjs.org/headers/dist/v18.16.1/x64/node.lib
which latest electron's node version.

I couldn't manage to use electron-rebuild for my private builded *.node files. Where can i find these headers to process manually?

I'm working on Windows 11. And need to target Windows.

I checked for electron storage and googled it for hours. Can't find anywhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.